# how to display a single database row after clicking on row from a iterated list in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, get

I have a if statement that goes through all of the title options and all of them are a link to the same page. The idea is that depending on which title option is clicked on the linked page will show the title in h3 tags.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    if ($queryResults > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $item =$row['title'];
              echo "<div>
                  <a href='p&fproject.php' name='project'>
                  <p>".$item."</p>
                  </a>
                  </div>";
      }
  }
}
if(isset($_POST['project'])){
  $id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? intval($_POST['id']): null;
  echo "<br>".$id;
}
?>
```

The last if statement was an attempt to identify the link that was clicked on by id instead of title but it doesn't work.

Page linked to:

```
<?php
include 'header1.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);




if ($queryResults > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    for ($i = 0; $i < $queryResults; $i++) {
        $item = $row['title'];
      echo "<div>
          <a href='' name='project'>
          <p>".$item."</p>
          </a>
          </div>";
          
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['project'])){
    $id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? intval($_POST['id']): null;
    echo "<br>".$id;
}

?>
```

Comment: Pass through the ID of the row as a URL param. `<a href="p&fproject.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"`. Then, on the next page lookup the specific row using that param in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: URL params come through in $_GET, not $_POST. Also, use a parameterized query when using that param in your `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, you risk SQL injection and the wrath of the SO community (which is worse than SQL injection IMO).

Comment: Also note that rows in an RDBMS table represent unordered sets. If you want rows in an order you must include an ORDER BY clause (and/or manipulate the resulting array in your application code)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that passing the post id in GET. What you want to do is put in the href your link `project.php` followed by a question mark with the id of the post, like this:  `'project.php?id='" . $row["id"] . "`, and then, in the page linked to, you can access that variable by doing `postId = $_GET["id"]` and making an SQL query on that id

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the SQL query for that id. I have tried doing $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id"; and then making a variable $postId = $_GET['id']; and echoing that variable but it isn't able to find the id.

Comment: When you echo the id, do you see it in the link bar? Like project.php?id=10